# Spring Boot, error when using data.sql file to import SQL into HSQL

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project which I'm setting up some tests for. I've setup an environment and configuration for 'test' using these details;

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.database = HSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect 
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver 
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:fujitest
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password =
```

I've exported a database using MySQLWorkbench, put this in my project root and named it 'data.sql', however when I run my tests I'm seeing the following error;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'db': Error creating bean with name 'repositories': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oAuthClients': Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oAuthClients': Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oAuthClients': Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:580)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:685)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:494)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runDataScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1723)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 95 more
```

The error appears to stem from the fact that it's reporting 'Unexpected token' when trying to parse the SQL file, but I can't figure out how to resolve the issue.

Here's a sample of a test SQL file I'm trying to import.

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` text,
  `password` text,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_token` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I've added extra logging settings as suggested, and now the output is as shown below;

```
Hibernate: 
    drop table account if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table account_device if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table oauth_client_details if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table stores if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table template if exists
Hibernate: 
    create table account (
        id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1),
        created_at DATETIME,
        email varchar(255),
        firstname varchar(255),
        is_active TINYINT,
        lastname varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
        reset_token varchar(255),
        roles varchar(255),
        updated_at DATETIME,
        username varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table account_device (
        id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1),
        account_id integer,
        device_id varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table oauth_client_details (
        client_id varchar(255) not null,
        access_token_validity integer,
        additional_information varchar(255),
        authorized_grant_types varchar(255),
        authorities varchar(255),
        autoapprove varchar(255),
        client_secret varchar(255),
        refresh_token_validity integer,
        resource_ids varchar(255),
        scope varchar(255),
        web_server_redirect_uri varchar(255),
        primary key (client_id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table stores (
        id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1),
        active TINYINT,
        address_line_1 varchar(255),
        address_line_2 varchar(255),
        county varchar(255),
        created_at DATETIME,
        kiosk_id varchar(255),
        latitude double,
        longitude double,
        postcode varchar(255),
        retailer_name varchar(255),
        store_number integer,
        telephone varchar(255),
        town varchar(255),
        updated_at DATETIME,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table template (
        id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1),
        content varchar(255),
        created_at DATETIME,
        name varchar(255),
        updated_at DATETIME,
        primary key (id)
    )
2018-01-13 09:40:51.247  INFO 64664 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-01-13 09:40:51.599  INFO 64664 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]
2018-01-13 09:40:51.601  WARN 64664 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'db': Error creating bean with name 'repositories': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oAuthClients': Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: CREATE TABLE `account` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `firstname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `lastname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `email` text, `password` text, `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, `roles` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `reset_token` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token:  required: (; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: CREATE TABLE `account` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `firstname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `lastname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `email` text, `password` text, `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, `roles` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `reset_token` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token:  required: (; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oAuthClients': Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: CREATE TABLE `account` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `firstname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `lastname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `email` text, `password` text, `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, `roles` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `reset_token` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token:  required: (; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthClientRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Volumes/WD%20-%20Projects/Projects/The-App-Developers/Fuji%20Rest%20API/target/classes/data.sql]: CREATE TABLE `account` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `firstname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `lastname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `username` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `email` text, `password` text, `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL, `roles` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `reset_token` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token:  required: (
2018-01-13 09:40:51.601  INFO 64664 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Hibernate: 
    drop table account if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table account_device if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table oauth_client_details if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table stores if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table template if exists
```

Comment: please post the sql file

Comment: I've added the contents of the file I'm trying to import

Answer (score 0):

I can see a weird colon here

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:fujitest
```

should it be

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:fujitest
```

? And each property should be alone on its line (maybe formatting was distorted by copying in here).

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database=HSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:fujitest
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Comment: I've changed the colon to an equals sign, and the same issue still occurs sadly.Yeh it looks like the formatting went wrong when I pasted it into SO

Comment: Can you please get rid of spaces around = sign in your properties as I suggested? The text of exception can mean a space is a culprit
In http://sqlfiddle.com/ I can successfully create a schema and a table using your sql command.

Comment: I've removed the spaces around = sign and the same error appears.

Comment: New suggestions. Can you please try other options for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto? And can you enable logging of executed sql commands?

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

To log values:

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace

Comment: I've done that and added the output to my question. It looks like Hibernate is creating the tables based on my entities, where I was hoping the have the creating of tables left to the data.sql file.

Comment: I've performed further debugging, and it appears than the data within data.sql must contain Hibernate queries and not standard SQL queries. As using 'drop table account if exists;' works, but 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`;' does not work.